# Storing a string in a integer variable in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = "Hi";
    char b = 'F';

    int c = a + b;

    printf("%d",a);        /* (1) */
    printf("%d",c);        /* (2) */ 
}
```

How come the output of the instruction (1) is 18537?
How is it storing the value in terms of ANSI standard

Instruction (2) is clear since we are basically adding 70 to 18537 which gives 18607

Can some one elaborate on how the value is being stored in the integer variable in terms of string ?

Comment: You are printing the address of the string `"Hi"` in an integer format and not the string itself. If you want to print the string, then write `printf("%s", a);`

Comment: `int a = "Hi";` is a constraint violation. The output of any executable for this code is completely undefined.

Comment: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html Try to convert 4869. But I have very different output.

Comment: Try to do some typecasting at least. char *a = "Hi"; printf("%d\n", * (short int *) a );

Answer (score 6):

**Compiler warnings for the win!**

```
$ cc -Wall -Wextra e.c 
e.c: In function ‘main’:
e.c:4:13: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     int a = "Hi";
             ^~~~
```

You assign the memory address of the string literal to the variable `a`. Well, in many cases you do. However, this is not guaranteed and there are potential problems involved with this. For example, an `int` may not be enough to hold the whole address.

It could be worth pointing out that this is not valid C code, so do not do this. According to https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p1 (Thank you @Lundin for providing the link):

> One of the following shall hold:112)
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right has arithmetic type;
> - the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a structure or union type compatible with the type of the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand is an atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer, and the right is a null pointer constant; or
> - the left operand has type atomic, qualified, or unqualified _Bool, and the right is a pointer.

See [Lundin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130401/6699433) for how to force the compiler to not accept invalid code.

Comment: "(Sorry if I'm sound a bit condescending, but learning HOW I to find the answer to your particular question is WAY more valuable than the answer itself.)" Yeah well how about practising what you preach. Some random web site is no canonical source. Rather, read this: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1

Comment: "discover.cs.ucsb.edu" is not an authoritative source for the C language.  In this case it seems to have misled you into thinking the code is valid. Googling for C language issues is a dangerous process as there is a lot more misinformation than valid information out there.

Comment: Interesting. I got a bit curious. Please tell me how the code cannot be valid if it compiles.

Comment: Because compilers allow invalid code in some cases. The language is defined by an ISO Standard, not by behaviour of gcc. You can use compiler switches to change this "warning" to an error if you like.

Comment: Thanks both of you.

Comment: *Strings are pointers, so although C will allow you to set an int equal to a pointer, the int will hold the value of the pointer itself rather than what it's pointing to.* Ouch. That's painfully bad. What a horrible way to mislead students. First, string literals are not really pointers. In some situations they decay to the address of the first element - which acts like a pointer, but it isn't a true pointer. That can be an important distinction and shouldn't be glossed over. And the `int` may very well not be able to hold the value of the pointer.  It won't on most 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 5):

`int a = "Hi";` is not valid C code and speculating about what it might do on a non-standard compiler isn't very meaningful.

The code is a constraint violation of the rules of simple assignment 6.5.16.1. You cannot assign a `char*` to an `int` implicitly, without a cast.

(If you want to block invalid C code from compiling on the gcc compiler, use `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.)

Comment: You could say the same thing, “not valid C code and speculating about what it might do on a non-standard compiler isn't very meaningful”, about a nonempty C file that does not end in a newline. In practice all compilers I have encountered, when they do not stop compilation on the missing newline (or on the missing cast), act as if it had been there in order to continue. I'm not sure if they are both meaningless or what makes one more meaningful than the other.

Comment: It can be useful to speculate about behaviour of invalid code; because this knowledge will help you in debugging other people's invalid code . Of course it is important to keep a mental distinction between what is Standard behaviour and what isn't.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, come on, seeing the question that was asked, I think that this level of answer as it is given here is completely ok. Telling something about what the effects of pointer to integer conversion might be here would not be helpful at this level of understanding.

Comment: @PascalCuoq The OP seems interested in what the standard says "How is it storing the value in terms of ANSI standard ", hence the answer.

Comment: @JensGustedt The question is asking “How come the output of the instruction (1) is 18537” as well as “How is it storing the value in terms of ANSI standard”. Saying that the program is not standard C answers the second question. This answer does not cover the first question, but a sentence saying that a conversion from pointer to integer took place would answer it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq But no such conversion is even allowed to take place, as you'd need valid code with compatible types. Besides, converting a pointer to `int` is poorly-specified behavior in the first place and `uintptr_t` should have been used instead.

Comment: @Lundin “but the program isn't even a C program since it's nonempty and does not end in a newline! You'd need a newline for it to be given any meaning”

Answer (score 1):

What happend is basilally this:

```
int a = "Hi" // you allocate 4 bytes and put in the chars ('H' [0x48], 'i'[0x69], '\0' [0x0], 1_byte_of_rubbish) so is OK
//a = 0x 00 00 48 69
```

Note that first bit is interpreted as the 'signum' on int. 
Also remember that the value in memory should be 0X[rubbish]004869

```
char b= 'F' //you allocate 1 byte and give value F [0x46] (unsigned)
// b=0x46
printf("%d",a) // print what is inside variable a (as SIGNED integer)
 int c = a + b // you add a (signed) and b (unsigned) and put result in c (signed) -> 0x[00]004869 + 46 = 0x000048AF 
//c=0x000048AF

printf("%d",c) // you print the content of c interpreted as signed int
```

Note that most compilers initiate to 0 the variables so you get 00 [004869], if compiler would'nt do so, you gat something unpredictable as result because first byte of int is not initialized

Remember also endianess -> int on intel (little endian) machine are read with LSB first so print %d will give you wrong values ( in your case [48][69][00][00] = 26952 read as little endian)

EDIT:
My suggestion is to always debug these cases "hexadecimally" so you can see exactly what is in each byte, decimel numbers sometimes (wehen it's about sorting) tells less.